# IE8 profiler what is the ActiveXObject displayed

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

I have been getting an error on a web page and checking it out with IE8 profiler lists at the top ActiveXObject, only the page is PHP on Apache without any embedded objects; I know I've checked the source.

Any ideas as to what the object is :-
The browser window hosting the page?
Malicious code?
Change of image in some type map to an activex control by mime type that can host it?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess an XMLHttpRequest.

Check your scripts for AJAX calls. If this is what's happening, you might consider changing your AJAX code to use the native “new XMLHttpRequest()” interface in preference to the old “new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHttp')” interface where available (IE7+).